# Percent of total time

Tags: sql-server, left-join, inner-join, percentage

I want to calculate a percent of total time for each ASSIGNEE_NAME

```
select
ROUND(CAST(
(
select 
CAST(AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND,  INF_TOWORK_TIME, INF_EXECUTE_TIME))as VARCHAR(10))
FROM [dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1] IM
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MYGROUPSM1] MG on MG.ID = IM.ASSIGNEE_NAME
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SCRELATIONM1] SC on IM.INCIDENT_ID = SC.SOURCE_ACTIVE
GROUP BY ASSIGNEE_NAME
)AS nvarchar),5)*100./
(
select 
CAST(AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND,  INF_TOWORK_TIME, INF_EXECUTE_TIME))as VARCHAR(10))
FROM [dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1] IM
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MYGROUPSM1] MG on MG.ID = IM.ASSIGNEE_NAME
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SCRELATIONM1] SC on IM.INCIDENT_ID = SC.SOURCE_ACTIVE
)
FROM [dbo].[PROBSUMMARYM1] IM
INNER JOIN [dbo].[MYGROUPSM1] MG on MG.ID = IM.ASSIGNEE_NAME
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SCRELATIONM1] SC on IM.INCIDENT_ID = SC.SOURCE_ACTIVE
GROUP BY ASSIGNEE_NAME
```

But i have an error : subquery returns more than 1 value this is not permitted when the subquery follows.
Where i made a mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have used two sub-query in ROUND, Most probably one of them return more than one row. So you should recheck your sub-query and it's joining condition to handle this error.